# How to place new lines of code on a new line in a knitted PDF in R Markdown?

Tags: r

I'm trying to knit a PDF document and set the following global settings because I want all the code and comments to appear inside the document (otherwise long lines of code or comments extend beyond the border of the page):

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message=FALSE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=40), tidy=TRUE)
```

The problem is that `tidy=TRUE` also causes some of my code to display on the same line despite being on a new line in my script. So this chunk:

```
ggplot(data = keffects_20, aes(x = k, y = avg_tests, group = pool_size)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab("Pool Size (k)") +
  ylab("Mean Number of Tests per Person") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1.25, 0.25)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[actually appear as this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fNUo.png)

[But I'd like it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZR54.png) (the same way it is written in the chunk).

The only way I'm able to get that desired format is by setting `tidy=FALSE` but then that causes my long lines of code to run off of the page. Is there any way to get both my long lines of code to stay on the page while also having new lines appear on a new line?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `tidy = FALSE` option is the only way to do what you want.  But you can limit that to just one statement by putting that statement in a chunk by itself.

Even better:  write your source in the format you want from the beginning, or format it in the source document, and leave `tidy = FALSE` in all chunks.